# In shared preferences how to store string array in android application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application am using list view in base adapter.

when i click the item its id store in shared preferences string array format. how to save multiple item id in string array format
[1,2,5,6] like this

Answer (score 10):

You can try using `JSONArray` as JSON is `light-weight` also, you can create a `JSONArray` and write it to SharedPreference as String.

**To write,**

```
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(1);
        jsonArray.put(2);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
        editor.commit();
```

**To Read,**

```
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", "[]"));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
                 Log.d("your JSON Array", jsonArray2.getInt(i)+"");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using API 11 then its possible by using `putStringSet`. Otherwise you may either convert your string array into a single string as mentioned by @hotverispicy or use SQLite database

Answer (score 3):

you can save it as string by `,`(comma) seperator and while fetching just use `split()`

```
string toPut="";

toPut += "listItem,";
```

set *toPut* in your `SharePreference` and commit()

To get the same in array: get *prefString* from `SharePreference`

```
String[] fetchArray= prefString.split(",");
```

Comment: Not so great if your strings have commas in them.

Comment: what about special character? like `@` `|` and so on.

Comment: Why don't you use regular expressions for the commas in the string.