# How to store array in an sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I am building an android application where the user selects his event from spinner tool.

The Spinner tool displays the array list that user had selected first time the application is launched.

Now I had parsed the array list from app launch page to spinner activity class an using it in spinner tool success full now.

Here is code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> array;
```

Here, the name array has the arraylist.
I need to store this in sharedprefrences. How can I do this ?

I am new to android.

Comment: Serialize the array ..

Comment: @MurtazaHussain How can I do..

Comment: @Sonam Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: @SweetWisherツ how ??

Comment: [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10241602/2591002)

Comment: can you switch to Set<String > @Sonam ??

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest using `putStringSet()` since it will screw up your arrayorder.

I suggest running a for loop over your array and giving them different key names. + in the end adding another String, that tells you how long the array is once you wanna read out the strings of the SharedPreferences.

**General settings:**

```js
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOURKEYFILE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

**Save String Array:**

```js
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("StringArrayElement" +i, array.get(i));
}
sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("StringArrayLength", array.size());
sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
```

**Read String Array:**

```js
array.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < sharedPreferencesEditor.getInt("StringArrayLength", 0) {
    array.add(sharedPreferencesEditor.getString("StringArrayElement" +i, "");
}
```

**NOTE:**
The above code is untested! Community correct me there if you find mistakes.

Comment: @Sonam Did you try out my solution yet? Do you understand my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array as Serializable object.

```
//save the task list to preference
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
try {
    editor.putString(ARRAY, ObjectSerializer.serialize(array));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
editor.commit();
```

And to retrieve it from SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

try {
    array = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(ARRAY,
         ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>())));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can get ObjectSerializer.java from [here](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)

Comment: In ObjectSerializer. java class error in WrappedIOException -WrappedIOException cannot be resolved.. please help me

Comment: Have you imported it ??

Comment: @Sonam For other solution you can convert arraylist to String array and save that array to SP and retrieve it easily too.!!

Comment: @PiyushGupta I used it but when I am Toasting the value save in SharedPreferences there is null toasting in it.

Comment: i m getting same error @PiyushGupta  mentioned over here working with custom objects how can i overcome in this situation ?

Comment: @Test123  how u resolved this issue WrappedIOException cannot be resolved

Comment: Use `Log.e("Serialization error: ", e.toString());` and import `import android.util.Log;`

Answer (score 0):

This code help to you maybe.You save list item by counter i.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
editor.putString(list.get(i)+i, list.get(i));
editor.commit();}
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
preferences.getString(list.get(i)+i, "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to go with *`Set<String>`*  as API version 11 introduced methods `putStringSet` and `getStringSet` which allows the developer to store a list of string values and retrieve a list of string values, respectively.

## Save list

```
// Save the list.
editor.putStringSet("array", myStrings);
editor.commit();
```

## Fetch list

```
// Get the current list.
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("YourActivityPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("array", new HashSet<String>());
```

Comment: Here is showing an error on putString - The method putStringSet(String, Set<String>) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>). please help to resolving it

Comment: You need to use `Set<String>` instead of  `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: But I am parsing the value from firstactivity to other so i am using ArrayList<String> so please tell me alter way to do this

Comment: Can i store the value of ArrayList<String> to Set<String> in same activity

Comment: Yes you can. ..please check the android developer site to work with set or refer java tutorial